# easy_install not working and package information required(connecting postgresql with python)

Tags: python, sql, easy-install

I am a naive user of python and sql(new to dbms). My question is that i am having pythonxy installed in my system(windows 7). Now in the command prompt of pythonxy when i try to install any package through

```
easy_install psyqlite
```

with psyqlite available at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysqlite , i get the message as invalid syntax, how can i install such packages.

Also that I am having query written for retrieval of data from postgresql and the retrieval is from R progamming language. Now I want to retrieve the data from pythonxy so which package should i use so that the code replication requires minimum effort or is the sql query same for any of the packages used once the connection of pythonxy with postgresql is done.I am having **psycopg2** installed.

Thank you

Comment: Can you post the error message the command prompt is giving you?

Comment: >>> easy_install pysqlite
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    easy_install pysqlite
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Well you could download the tar file, use 7zip to uncompress it and then run the good old python setup.py install. I think it deserves a go.

Answer (score 0):

alternative solution would be using pip

pip install psyqlite